# Why ((counter++)) fails when counter == 0?

Tags: linux, bash

This code doesn't give any failure, but if you use counter++ the first iteration fails.

```
parameters="one two three"  
counter=0

  for option in $parameters
  do
    eval $option=${args[$counter]}
    ((counter = counter + 1)) # If you do ((counter++)) it fails the first iteration, weird.
    echo $option $?
  done
```

Here is what I mean:

```
ulukai@computer:~$ bash -x test.sh 
+ parameters='one two three'
+ counter=0
+ for option in '$parameters'
+ eval one=
++ one=
+ (( counter++ ))
+ echo one 1
one 1
+ for option in '$parameters'
+ eval two=
++ two=
+ (( counter++ ))
+ echo two 0
two 0
+ for option in '$parameters'
+ eval three=
++ three=
+ (( counter++ ))
+ echo three 0
three 0
ulukai@computer:~$ vi test.sh
ulukai@computer:~$ bash -x test.sh 
+ parameters='one two three'
+ counter=0
+ for option in '$parameters'
+ eval one=
++ one=
+ (( counter=counter+1 ))
+ echo one 0
one 0
+ for option in '$parameters'
+ eval two=
++ two=
+ (( counter=counter+1 ))
+ echo two 0
two 0
+ for option in '$parameters'
+ eval three=
++ three=
+ (( counter=counter+1 ))
+ echo three 0
three 0
```

I think that explains it enough to whomever would understand this issue, but because I need to add more text in order to submit this I am writing this line.

Comment: Nope, but the first iteration gives an exit 1 code, meaning that if you set your scripts with `set -e` and `set -o pipefail` like I do, they stop running. Other than that is all good.

Comment: There are many bad practices here to loop over the argument list here. Using `eval` and using a for-loop over variable contents. Let us know your requirements in general to get better/safe ways to do

Comment: I need to iterate over a series of parameters and those parameters need to be assigned a value from the arguments provided, hence the eval and the specific order of iteration of the for loop. Didn't want to provide all manner of details as I just wanted an answer for something specific but if you know of better ways of doing this I am always keen on learning a better way, even if out of the scope of this question ;-)

Comment: You need to provide some sample values of `args` and `parameters` here to understand your use-case better

Comment: Use `declare` instead of `eval`; it is slightly safer as it cannot execute (as much) arbitrary shell code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i++` would return the old value of `i` so the first `counter++` would return 0 which means FALSE in Bash's arithmetic context.

(Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators )